# FileSystemRights: Check if it contains specific rights?

Tags: powershell

I want to test if the FileSystemRights contains and not contains specific rights.

I am reading out the FileSystemRights and it looks like this:

```
FileSystemRights: Write, ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
```

It's of type FileSystemRights, so not an array or list.

When I use `if ($fsr.ToString() -contains 'ReadAndExecute')` it doesn't work.

What is the correct way to check if it does or does not contain something?

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
$fsr.ToString().Contains("ReadAndExecute")
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider comparing `FileSystemRights.value__` with [`System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) enum as follows:

```
$getAcl = Get-Acl -Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName
'--- compare (enum) '-or':'
$getAcl.Access |
    Where-Object { $_.FileSystemRights.value__ -or 
        [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::ReadAndExecute} |
    Select-Object -property FileSystemRights, AccessControlType, IdentityReference
"`n--- with (string) '-match':`n"
$getAcl.Access |
    Where-Object { $_.FileSystemRights.ToString() -match 'ReadAndExecute' } |
    Select-Object -property FileSystemRights, AccessControlType, IdentityReference
```

**Output** shows that `ReadAndExecute` right might be hidden under a *major* one: `D:\PShell\SO\62286157.ps1`

```
--- compare (enum) '-or':

           FileSystemRights AccessControlType IdentityReference               
           ---------------- ----------------- -----------------               
                FullControl             Allow BUILTIN\Administrators          
                FullControl             Allow NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM             
        Modify, Synchronize             Allow NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
ReadAndExecute, Synchronize             Allow BUILTIN\Users                   

--- with (string) '-match':

ReadAndExecute, Synchronize             Allow BUILTIN\Users
```